# Bold font in \citep

Tags: overleaf

Is there an option which allows me to bold \citep text? Here's a MWE explaining my problem:

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\cite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references.bib}
```

```
\citep{test}
```

Comment: Welcome. If you don't have many citations simply `\textbf{\citep{...}}`.

Comment: For global option use `\newcommand{\mycitep}[1]{\textbf{\citep{#1}}}` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482899/i-want-my-citation-should-be-in-bold-in-my-text)